# How can I change the position of the header in Android TV app from left to top?

Tags: java, android

[image: Header to the left]

The code only allows me to either hide or disable/enable the header to the right. But instead of left, I want the position of the header to be centered at the top so that I can switch between categories. I have tried editing some code I am sorry I know nearly nothing about Java and Android TV apps, but I have a uni project and I need some help. If you can provide a code that I can copy/paste or a very detailed how-to, I would really appreciate it.

```
 private void setupUIElements() {
        setBadgeDrawable(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logo_white));
        setHeadersState(HEADERS_ENABLED); This in the line
        setHeadersTransitionOnBackEnabled(true);
        setBrandColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.indigo_dark));
```